# Django input_formats removes help_text? I want only to change the way one DateField is displayed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

#### My Problem

My problem is that when setting an `input_formats` on my `AbonnentForm(ModelForm)` in `forms.py`, the model's `help_text` is not displayed in the HTML form.

I want only to change the way one DateField is displayed.

What am I doing wrong?

#### My Code

This is my models.py (shortened)
    from django.db import models

```
def get_letzte_ausgabe_default():
    return date(date.today().year, 12, 1) if date.today() > date(2017, 12, 26) else date(date.today().year + 1, 12, 1)

class Abonnent(models.Model):
    erste_ausgabe = models.DateField(default=get_letzte_ausgabe_default(),
                                     verbose_name="Erste Ausgabe",
                                     help_text="Eingabe im Format MM/JJJJ. Zum Beispiel: 01/2018)
```

This is my forms.py (complete)

```
from django.forms import ModelForm, DateField, DateInput
from .models import Abonnent


class AbonnentForm(ModelForm):
    # WHEN I ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE, THE HELP_TEXT IS NOT DISPLAYED UNDER THE HTML-FORM
    erste_ausgabe = DateField(input_formats=['%m %Y'],
                              widget=DateInput(format='%m %Y'))
    class Meta:
        model = Abonnent
        fields = '__all__'
```

And this is my template (shortened)

```
<div class="col-sm {% if form.letzte_ausgabe.errors %} has-danger {% endif %}">
  <label class="col-form-label" for="{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.id_for_label }}">{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.label }}</label>
  <input id="{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.id_for_label }}" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.value }}" name="{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.html_name }}" placeholder="MM/JJJJ" aria-describedby="{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.id_for_label }}Help">
  {% if form.letzte_ausgabe.help_text %}<small id="{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.id_for_label }}Help" class="form-text text-muted">{{ form.letzte_ausgabe.help_text }}</small>{% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the `input_formats` and `widget` inside the `__init__` method.

```
class AbonnentForm(ModelForm):
    # ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AbonnentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['erste_ausgabe'].input_formats=['%m %Y']
        self.fields['erste_ausgabe'].widget=DateInput(format='%m %Y')
```

This avoids having to duplicate the `help_text` in the model form as in Nik's answer.

Comment: Oh yeah! That's a much better answer than mine. What happened to my DRY principles :) ? I'll not delete it, though, I'll better let it there float...

Comment: This does not work: `self.fields['erste_ausgabe'].widget=DateInput(format='%m %Y')`. I tried alternatives like `self.fields['letzte_ausgabe'].widget.format='%m %Y'`, but it would not apply. Any ideas?

Comment: `'%m %Y'` is a valid `strformat`, I don't see a problem there. What doesn't work is that the field value is shown as 'Dez. 1, 2018' instead of '12 2018'. I know it's a different question, that is why I already accepted. Thought, you might know a quick solution, though.

Comment: Setting a field's widget in the `__init__` method is a common approach. I've tested the above code, and setting `self.fields['erste_ausgabe'].widget=DateInput(format='%m %Y')` works.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, but I omitted the default value, and I suspect that is the issue. I created a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908002/datefield-formatting-problems). Thanks for your support.

Comment: Your issue is because you are rendering the form field manually in the template. If you use `{{ form.erste_ausgabe }}` then the date will be displayed in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are "overriding" the `erste_ausgabe` field inside the `ModelForm` and, thus, the `help_text` is not displayed.

According the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) you can re-specify the `help_text` inside the `ModelForm` class.

```
class AbonnentForm(ModelForm):
    erste_ausgabe = DateField(input_formats=['%m %Y'],
                              widget=DateInput(format='%m %Y'),
                              help_text="Eingabe im Format MM/JJJJ. Zum Beispiel: 01/2018")
```